# How to detect boostrap card-header hoverover in typescript?

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8

I have a card in bootstrap with a button in the header, I would like to display the button only when the user is doing a hover over the header, something like:
`ngIf="card-heaver.hoverover"`.
so I need to detect the hover over in the html or in the typescript side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do it that way for several reasons including performance, keep such things on the presentation layer and the compositor thread instead like so;

```css
.card-header > .btn {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.card-header:hover > .btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Quote <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a great weekend, cheers!